# <pre> tag does not work on bootstrap 4 modal

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to use `<pre>` tag in a bootstrap 4 modal but it does not seem to work correctly. Here is the output of the json put inside of `<pre>` tag. I know I am missing something there but not sure what it might be:

Here is the html code:

```html
<div class="modal" id="error_jobs_@guid" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="error_jobs_@guid">Error</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                        </button>
      </div>
      <table class="table no-margin">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <pre>@JsonConvert.SerializeObject(item)</pre>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Any idea why it might happen because I remember it worked in bootstrap 3 ?
[image: The image]

EDIT 1:

Here is a runnable example: [here](http://jsfiddle.net/aq9Laaew/111741/)

Considered using `<code>` and it was a little bit better but anyway not the desired result. Actually I used all combinations with `<pre>` and `<code>` but none of them works correctly. Here is an image how it looks like using `<code>` tag:

[image]

Comment: Most likely because the parent of the table is a flex item (Bootstrap 4 use Flexbox, 3 does not). Provide a [mcve] showing that part of the HTML/CSS too.

Comment: check this http://jsfiddle.net/4o51ve29/

Comment: @LGSon here is the complete modal html code, only one custom class added to table to remove margins

Comment: We would like a _runnable_ code snippet, with the linked bootstrap version being used, and any custom classes that effect the given elements, and the actual JSON string of course. Add it to the snippet I created in your question.

Comment: @LGSon added a runnable example.

Comment: Interesting. What about to use <code> instead of <pre>? https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/content/code/

Answer (score 1):

It's not indenting as it should because the "JSON object" is basicaly a string without the propper indentation in your html.

You can parse the string to json object and then parse the json object back to string to get the right indentation.

If you are getting the json from database you can just parse it to string and add it to the html.

```
var jsonString = document.getElementById("pretty-json").innerHTML;
document.getElementById("pretty-json").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(jsonString), null, 2);
```

You can see the example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/nw3dqc9r/).